# Convert japanese kanji number to western number php

Tags: php

I want to convert Japanese number format to normal western number, for example:

```
十万 -> 100,000
三-> 3
八十四->84
四十万四-> 400,004
```

If you guys know some fast way to convert any Japanese kanji number to western numbers I would appreciate.

Comment: How do larger numbers get represented - is it possible to have 兆 and 億 in the number?

Comment: The solution below shows that implementation as well. If you want even bigger numbers just keep the same idea of the code below

Answer (score 1):

I am using this following code to convert:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[1000000000000] = '兆';
$arr[100000000] = '億';
$arr[10000] = '万';
$arr[1000] = '千';
$arr[100] = '百';
$arr[10] = '十';
$arr[9] = '九';
$arr[8] = '八';
$arr[7] = '七';
$arr[6] = '六';
$arr[5] = '五';
$arr[4] = '四';
$arr[3] = '三';
$arr[2] = '二';
$arr[1] = '一';

function convertNumJpToEn($jpNum, $arr){  
    $arrayWithNumbers = mb_str_split($jpNum);
    $num = null;
    foreach($arrayWithNumbers as $jpKanji){
        $keyVal = array_search($jpKanji, $arr);
        if($num == null){
            $num = $keyVal;
        }else{
            if($keyVal < 10){
                $num = $num + $keyVal;
            }else{
                $num = $num * $keyVal;
            }
        }
    }   
    print_r($arrayWithNumbers);
    return $num;
}
```

Comment: You could invert your array to have something like `$arr['兆'] = 1000000000000;`, this would mean you don't need the `array_search()`.